# error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

class base {
 public:
    int lookup(char c);
}; // class base

int base::lookup(char c)
{
    cout << c << endl;
} // base::lookup

int main() {
    base b;
    char c = "i";
    b.lookup(c);
} // main
```

On Compiling above code I am getting below error :

> g++ -c test.cpp test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:20:10:
>   error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try replacing

```
 char c = "i";
```

with

```
 char c = 'i';
```

Comment: @VarunVyas what error message do you get when you change that line?

Comment: If you're using up to two characters like ab or more, then it's rather a string not char @VarunVyas

Answer (score 12):

`"i"` is not a character, it's a character array that basically decays to a pointer to the first element.

You almost certainly want `'i'`.

Alternatively, you may actually *want* a lookup based on more than a single character, in which case you *should* be using `"i"` but the type in that case is `const char *` rather than just `char`, both when defining `c` and in the `base::lookup()` method.

However, if that were the case, I'd give serious thought to using the C++ `std::string` type rather than `const char *`. It may not be *necessary,* but using C++ strings may make your life a lot easier, depending on how much you want to manipulate the actual values.

Answer (score 11):

`"i"` is a string literal, you probably wanted a char literal: `'i'`.

String literals are null terminated arrays of `const char` (which are implicitly converted to `char const*` when used in that expression, hence the error).

char literals are just `char`s