# Answer Review - Invalid Conversion from 'const char*' to 'char'

Tags: c++, char, constants

Upon research I actually found the answer to my previous question.  Why the heck is the computer telling me I can't define the elements of my array.

```
#include <iostream>


 using namespace std;
 int x;
 int y;

 int main(){

 char DuplicateDeleter[6];
    //we must define each element
DuplicateDeleter[0] = 'a';
DuplicateDeleter[1] = 'b';
DuplicateDeleter[2] = 'c';
DuplicateDeleter[3] = 'd';
DuplicateDeleter[4] = 'e';
DuplicateDeleter[5] = 'f';
 }
```

The answer was that I had to use 'a' over "a", and my question is what's the difference between these two?  I was under the suspicion that they pretty much did the same thing.  What is "x" telling the computer that 'x' isn't?

[error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026567/error-invalid-conversion-from-const-char-to-char-fpermissive)   - source

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: `"a"` is a string literal, which is two characters, a and a null terminator. `'a'` is an integer with the value of the character a. You can assign that to a char variable.

Answer (score 1):

`"x"` is `NULL` terminated character array. It is having 2 characters i.e. `{'a', '\0'}`. 'x' is a single character.

You can verify it by following code snippet. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/OXu9ci):

```
int main() {
    cout<<"sizeof(\"x\") = " <<sizeof("x") <<endl<<"sizeof('x') = " <<sizeof('x') <<endl;

    cout<<"Content of \"x\" are(in Hexadecimal): "<<endl;
    char x[] = "x";
    cout.setf(ios::hex, ios::basefield);
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof("x"); i++)
         cout<<"\t "<<(int)x[i] <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**Output**:

```
sizeof("x") = 2
sizeof('x') = 1
Content of "x" are(in Hexadecimal): 
     78
     0
```

You can see more information [here](http://classes.mst.edu/compsci1570/ntca.htm) and [here](http://www-ee.eng.hawaii.edu/~tep/EE160/Book/chap7/subsection2.1.1.2.html)

Answer (score 1):

`'a'` is the character "a". Just one character, not a string.

`"a"` is the an array of two `char`s; it's equivalent to this: `char a[2] = {'a', '\0'};`  The extra character (`\0`) is the null-terminator, since raw strings in C/C++ don't maintain their length explicitly.