# Why error on const char* to const char conversion?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, char

The following code works:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char *ssid =  "Your wifi Network name";     // replace with your wifi ssid and wpa2 key
const char *pass =  "Network password";

WiFiClient client;

void setup() 
{
   Serial.begin(9600);
   delay(10);

   Serial.println("Connecting to ");
   Serial.println(ssid); 

   WiFi.begin(ssid, pass); 
   while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) 
   {
      delay(500);
      Serial.print(".");
   }
   Serial.println("");
   Serial.println("WiFi connected"); 
}
```

But when the line:

`const char *pass =  "Network password";`

is replaced with:

`const char pass =  "Network password";`

The compiler throws an error.

Why does the character pointer (I think it is a pointer) make the code work, when it is never used elsewhere throughout the code?

I have had a look at the following link, but I am getting confused about the explanation:

[error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char’ [-fpermissive]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12026567/)

Comment: Were you trying to do this "char ssid =  "Your wifi Network name"; '?

Comment: I was wondering why I needed the *char and why char wouldn't work

Comment: `char` is a single character. It can't hold `"Network password"`. You need an array to copy the literal into or to just point at the literal they way you are doing in the working code.

Comment: char is just the representation of one character.
const char * is a pointer to a single character. A string literal in C++ and C is a block of characters in memory that occur one after the other (contigious is the word for that). Adding the pointer points to that block of characters in memory. A string in C also always ends in a null character, so when you have a pointer to the start of the string a program knows the string continues until a null character (a zero) is encountered.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense, thanks. I think I will do some more research into this though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `char` is a single character.  A `char*` is a pointer to a `char`.

A **string literal** is a fixed-length `const char[]` array of characters. You can assign a `const char[]` array to a `const char*` pointer, as the reference to the array name will *decay* into a pointer to the 1st element in the array.  That is why `const char *ssid = "Your wifi Network name";` works.

You can't assign a `const char[]` array or a `const char*` pointer to a single `char`.  That is why `const char pass = "Network password";` does not work.

And yes, the pointers are being used in the code, despite your claim that they are not.  The `ssid` pointer is being passed as input to `Serial.println()` , and the `ssid` and `pass` pointers are both being passed as input to `WiFi.begin()`.  Both of those functions take strings as their input.

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting a bit confused why you need a pointer?

Comment: Then I suggest you read up more on what pointers actually are. That is a whole topic of its own, beyond the scope of this question.